# How do I perform a simple GET request with cookies in C#

Tags: c#, http, cookies, network-programming, get

Everything I find is either about a POST request or does not assume cookies.

I have an URL like this:

```
http://page.com/find/1,1,1,find.html?advanced=1&param1=val1&param2[]=val2
```

When put into a browser, this will direct me to a search results page. Now I would like to replicate it in a C# program. I have this so far:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
((HttpWebRequest)req).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2";
req.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

When I run it, it returns a "please login" page, as expected. But there is a problem with one of the parameters. This is the response URL:

```
http://page.com/login.html?ref=find/1,1,1,find.html?advanced=1&param1=val1&param2=Array
```

So, two questions: what might have happened to param2? And how do I add cookies to this?

EDIT: Managed to set the cookies by casting to `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

As **devio** said you should use HttpWebRequest. I did dirty test to check it.

Prepare cookies to send. I made available for whole localhost:

```
HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test.php");
rq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
rq.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("test", "xxxx", "/", "localhost"));
```

Your script should set cookies to make them available in response. And you could use them.

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
foreach(var c in resp.Cookies)
{
    Debug("{0}: {1}", c.Name, c.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this code piece:**

```
Cookie SessionCookie = new Cookie("{CookieName}", {Cookievalue})
{
    Domain = "{domain you want to hit}", Path = "/", Expired = false, HttpOnly = true 
};

CookieContainer SessionCookieHolder = new CookieContainer();

SessionCookie.Add(SessionCookie);

try
{
   HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("{URL}");
   WebReq.CookieContainer = SessionCookie;
   WebReq.Method = "GET/POST/HEAD"; //depending on the request type//
   WebReq.KeepAlive = true;
   HttpWebResponse Resp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
}

catch(Exception ex)

{
   string ExceptionReader = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. While this code may work, answers with an explanation are much higher regarded here. Can you please [edit] your answer and add some prose explaining the code and how it solves the problem? That way others can learn better from it rather than just copying & pasting something off the web.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored in the [HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies.aspx) properties.

For subsequent requests, you need to add the response's cookies to the request's cookie container.